# trying to save dices-objects as separate session-variables, but wont work (yahtzeegame php)

Tags: php, session, variable-assignment, simulation

I have 3 dice objects which after having been thrown once, I would like user to be able to choose 1 of these dices, whichever is chosen, is to be saved to a new separate session-variable to hold the dice-object representing the dice-number which user did enter.

And then my intent was for the rest of the dice-objects to be saved to another separate session-variable to hold the ones to be thrown again.

But this doesn't seem to work the way I want -> Trying to combine the use of $_GET-variables to hold the number inputted via hidden form textfield, and session-variables to hold the dice-objects.

The code looks like so:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

require_once('../CDiceSvg.php');
require_once('../CDiceGame.php');

session_start();

//Initiate 3 variables to hold the dices
$_SESSION['yatzygame']['dices'] = Array();

//Initiate 2 variables to maintain the dices to save respectively reroll.
$_SESSION['yatzygame']['dicesToSave'] = Array();
$_SESSION['yatzygame']['dicesToReRoll'] = Array();


//Initiate the 3 dices.
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
    $_SESSION['yatzygame']['dices'][$i] = new CDiceSvg();
}

//If game has not yet been started:
if(!isset($_GET['roundcounter']))
{
    //Then hide the continue and enough-buttons
    $status = "";
    $status2 = "style=\"display: none;\"";
    $throwCounter = 0;

}

//If the "kasta"-button has been pressed -> Start the game:
if(isset($_GET['button']) && $_GET['button'] == "kasta")
{
    $status = "style=\"display: none;\"";
    $status2 = "";
    $_GET['roundcounter']++;
    $throwCounter = $_GET['roundcounter'];

    //Throw the dices
    for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
    {
        $_SESSION['yatzygame']['dices'][$i]->ThrowDieEnhanced();
    }
}

//If game has been started/If the first dices has been tossed:
if($_GET['roundcounter'] == 1)
{
    //Fetch the dices values (given as integers):
    $diceValues = Array();

    for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
    {
        $diceValues[$i] = $_SESSION['yatzygame']['dices'][$i]->GetLastThrow();
    }

    //Print the dices generated values:
    print_r($diceValues);



}

if(isset($_GET['dicekeeping']))
{
    //Store the chosen dice to keep/save:
    $dicesToKeep = $_GET['dicekeeping'];
    echo "<br><br>" . $dicesToKeep;
}
```

/*
Code seems to work upuntil HERE BELOW: It's just like the dice objects isn't correctly saved into the new separated session-variables...
*/

```
//Save the dices until the next round accordingly to user-choice:
if(isset($_GET['dicekeeping']) && $_GET['button'] == "continue")
{
    for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
    {
        if($_GET['dicekeeping'] == $i)
        {
            $_SESSION['yatzygame']['dicesToSave'][$i] = $_SESSION['yatzygame']['dices'][$i];

        }else
        {
            $_SESSION['yatzygame']['dicesToReRoll'][$i] = $_SESSION['yatzygame']['dices'][$i];

        }
    }

    print_r($_SESSION['yatzygame']['dicesToSave']);

    //Store the values to check so everything goes according to plan:
    $printValuesForSave = Array();

    $counter = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['yatzygame']['dicesToSave'] as $diceObj)
    {
        $printValuesForSave[$counter] = $diceObj->GetLastThrows();
        $printValuesForSave[$counter] = $printValuesForSave[$counter][0];
        $counter++;
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
    print_r($printValuesForSave);
    print_r($_SESSION['yatzygame']['dicesToReRoll']);

    $_GET['roundcounter']++;
    $throwCounter = $_GET['roundcounter'];
}



//Go to Round 2 and print-out new state of the dices and handle previous choices:
if($_GET['roundcounter'] == 2)
{
    foreach($_SESSION['yatzygame']['dicesToSave'] as $diceSaved)
    {
        echo "Dices saved from last round: {$diceSaved}";
    }

    //Reroll dices indirectly chosen to be rerolled earlier:
    foreach($_SESSION['yatzygame']['dicesToReRoll'] as $dice)
    {
        $dice->ThrowDieEnhanced();
    }

    //Get the new values from the rerolled dices:
    $newValuesArray = Array();
    foreach($_SESSION['yatzygame']['dicesToReRoll'] as $diceNmbr => $diceValue)
    {
        $newValuesArray[$diceNmbr] = $_SESSION['yatzygame']['dicesToReRoll'][$diceNmbr]->GetLastThrow();
    }

    foreach($newValuesArray as $newDiceValue => $newValue)
    {
        echo "<br><br>Here comes the {$newDiceValue} new value: {$newValue}";
    }
}

//Print the form..
echo <<<EOD
        <form action="framework_Test.php" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="roundcounter" value="{$throwCounter}">
        <button type="submit" name="button" {$status} value="kasta">Kasta</button>
        <input type="text" name="dicekeeping" {$status2} autofocus>
        <input type="hidden" name="dicestokeep" value="{$dicesToKeep}">

        <button type="submit" name="button" {$status2}value="continue">Fortsätt</button>
        <button type="submit" name="button" {$status2} value="enough">Nöjd</button>
        <a href="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" {$status}>Starta om</a>
EOD;
?>
```

For the classes that is beeing used code comes below:
The core code which CDiceSvg.php extends of which I mostly take use in this example;

```
private $iLastThrow = 0;


//Function that throws a dice and returns a random value
private function ThrowDie()
{
    return rand(1,6);   
}

public function ThrowDieEnhanced()
{
    $this->iLastThrow = 0;
    $this->iLastThrow = $this->ThrowDie();
    return $this->iLastThrow;
}
    public function GetLastThrow()
{
    return $this->iLastThrow;
}
```

Im still quite new to this whole PHP-language coding and not very familiar with SESSION's, But in my eyes, the logic of this "framework"- for yahtzee/code should be sufficient, Have no idea whatsoever what is going wrong :/
Please help! Been stuck on this problem for over 4 days now...

Metaphorically speaking I have banged my head against the walls so much that it's no longer recognizeable, have been pulling my hair to baldness for this problem and started climbing the walls - No matter how hard I stare through the code nothing comes to mind :/
- In other words, desperate need of enlightenment :)

Thx in advance, and btw. Im open to suggestions if there are better ways of doing what I seek to do.

Answer (score 0):

someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm not sure if the `++` accumulator operator is possible with `$_GET` variables. where you have:

```
$_GET['roundcounter']++;
$throwCounter = $_GET['roundcounter'];

.
.
.

if($_GET['roundcounter'] == 2)
{
    ...
}
```

I think you'd have to do something like:

```
$throwCounter = $_GET['roundcounter'];
$throwCounter++;

.
.
.

if($throwCounter == 2)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It seems to work, since when I run the code, the throwCounter increases to 2 lateron in the codes next stages.

But Im not sure, I do however not think that is the problem I am experiencing, or could it be? ;o